# SIGSEGV ERROR causing wierd crash on app launch and few api calls

Tags: ios, objective-c, crash, crash-reports, segmentation-fault

From the breadcrumbs , I figured out that the app crashes right after launch and few api calls. What seems to be the issue here? Can't paste any relevant code here as this crash is not reproducible. Following is the stack trace:

```
Crashed Thread

1   CFNetwork 0x2da6bf95 _ZN8CFObject8AllocateEmRK7CFClassPK13__CFAllocator + 105
2   CFNetwork 0x2da82bd3 _ZN19HTTPConnectionCache21createEmptyCacheEntryEv + 20
3   CFNetwork 0x2da82a43 _ZN19HTTPConnectionCache34_onqueue_enqueueRequestForProtocolEP12HTTPProtocolP15__CFHTTPMessage + 64
4   CFNetwork 0x2dada00d ___ZN19HTTPConnectionCache25enqueueRequestForProtocolEP12HTTPProtocolP15__CFHTTPMessage_block_invoke + 14
5   CoreFoundation 0x2ddb68f1 CFArrayApplyFunction + 34
6   CFNetwork 0x2da7f6bb _ZN19RunloopBlockContext7performEv + 180
7   CFNetwork 0x2da7f579 _ZN17MultiplexerSource7performEv + 218
8   CFNetwork 0x2da7f40d _ZN17MultiplexerSource8_performEPv + 46
9   CoreFoundation 0x2de4e20b __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ +      12
10  CoreFoundation 0x2de4d6db __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 204
11  CoreFoundation 0x2de4becf __CFRunLoopRun + 620
12  CoreFoundation 0x2ddb6ebf CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 520
13  CoreFoundation 0x2ddb6ca3 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 104
14  Foundation 0x2e7f7087 +[NSURLConnection(Loader) _resourceLoadLoop:] + 316
15  Foundation 0x2e86ca5f __NSThread__main__ + 1060
16  libsystem_pthread.dylib 0x38d29919 _pthread_body + 138
17  libsystem_pthread.dylib 0x38d2988b _pthread_start + 100
18  libsystem_pthread.dylib 0x38d27aa4 thread_start + 6
```